# Inheriting constructors work only partially

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, multiple-constructors, inheriting-constructors

I have following class, written so, as to work completely, whatever the typedef is:

```
class A
{
protected:
    typedef uchar mDataType;
    std::vector<mDataType> mData;

    uint32 mWidth;
    uint32 mHeight;

    friend class C;
public:
    A();
    A(void* data, uint32 width, uint32 height, size_t dataSize);
    A(const A& other);
    A(A&& other);
    A& operator=(const A& other);
    A& operator=(A&& other) = delete;

    ~A();
}
```

I wanted to make a subclass, that is actually almost the same, apart from overloaded typedef:

```
class B : public A
{
private:
    typedef float mDataType;
public:
    using A::A;
    using A::operator=;
};
```

What I wanted to achieve was to make a class B, that is:
 - identical to A
 - has all of As functions (there are few member functions in A, that I've not written)
 - has all of As operators
 - has all of As constructors
 - has different typedef
 - has the same destructor

My code does not work, because I can't call B(void*, uint32, uint32, size_t), which is what I want. (Intellisense shows me only B() and B(const B&) as available constructors).

Comment: What compiler are you using? Are you sure you're compiling in C++11 (or higher) mode?

Comment: Which compiler? Visual Studio supports inheriting constructors only since 2015.

Comment: Thank You very much! I'm using VS2013. Time to get 2015, I guess...

Comment: You're aware that `mData` still is a `std::vector<uchar>`, and that all uses of `mDataType` in the baseclass refer to `uchar`, regardless of what `mDataType` in the subclass is?

Comment: I wanted to make it so baseclass object has std::vector<uchar> and subclass object has std::vector<float>. Inside member function implementations I use only mDataType, so changing only it, should be sufficient I hope?

Comment: @MKK The only thing you can override is virtual member functions. Redefining a type alias (or a member variable) in a subclass has no effect on the base class. What you're looking for is a class template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inheriting constructors are [only supported since VC++2014 CTP 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/06/11/c-11-14-feature-tables-for-visual-studio-14-ctp1.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want `template` instead of inheritance:

```
template <typename T>
class Mat
{
private:
    using DataType = T;
    std::vector<T> mData;

    uint32 mWidth;
    uint32 mHeight;

    friend class C;
public:
    Mat();
    Mat(void* data, uint32 width, uint32 height, size_t dataSize);
    Mat(const Mat& other);
    Mat(A&& other);
    Mat& operator=(const Mat& other);
    Mat& operator=(Mat&& other) = delete;

    ~Mat();
};


using A = Mat<uchar>;
using B = Mat<float>;
```

Comment: I preferred using inheritance, because using pointer to baseclass I could operate on baseclass and/or subclass.
Maybe I did wrong and proper way would be to make abstract baseclass and 2 subclasses? Then I could operate on both, while using the same pointer (to baseclass).

I want 2 classes, that I can refer to using 1 pointer, because I have std::vector of those classes in other class (class C) and want to avoid code duplication. As I wrote in question, my code works with whatever DataType you give it - thats why I also thought about template as well....but what about those pointers?

Comment: @MKK: As state in comment, in your code, `B` and `A` are nearly identical, they both have `std::vector<uchar> mData;` (yes `uchar`). Hard to tell exactly how to design your code without knowing `class C`. but currently `B` is nearly useless. (I suspect also that your constructor that take `void*` is for a generically which can be solve differently)